# How do i restrict the width of a html document to be not go beyond the width of the screen of a mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, sass

Im making a small game demo that plays in a web browser. I am making it strictly for mobile browsers, the game looks perfect in google chromes emulator, but when i host the web app and open it on a cell phone the width of the game grows way beyond 100%.

I have already set the viewport tag, I have the width set to 100%, and its even set to a max width of 390px. This way even if i open it on desktop im still getting a screen size that is for mobile. For some reason despite the width being set to 390px, it opens at like 1000px wide when i open the site on mobile, which obviously messes up the proportions of the entire demo. My hunch was that the images inside some of the div tags are forcing the screen to be wider, but i dont understand why this is happening on mobile and not on desktop. Like the images are perfectly contained inside their elements when i open the app on desktop. I would say the images are even contained on mobile, but the width of everything acts as if its not set.   It happens on mobile chrome and safari.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 390px){
  .element{
    with: 100%;
    max-width: 390px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not work. As i said the element is already set to a max width of 390px, regardless when i open the site on mobile its still too big

Comment: or you can use percent values instead. or if your want to force the value to 390px do it like thise **max-width: 390px !important;**